# SQL SELECT compare values from two tables (without UNION ALL)

Tags: sql, db2, where-clause

I have table T1:

```
ID  IMPACT
1     3
```

I have table T2

```
PRIORITY URGENCY
   1        2
```

I need to do the SELECT from T1 table.

I would like to get all the rows from T1 where IMPACT is greater than PRIORITY from T2.

I am working in some IBM application where it is **only possible** to start with SQL statement after the WHERE clause from the first table T1.

So query (unfortunately) must always start with `"SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE..."`
This cannot be changed (please have that in mind).

This means that I cannot use some JOIN or UNION ALL statement after the `"FROM T1"` part because I can start to write SQL query only after the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT * FROM T1
WHERE 
IMPACT> SELECT PRIORITY FROM T2 WHERE URGENCY=2
```

But I am getting an error for this statement.
Please is it possible to write SQL query starting with:

```
SELECT * FROM T1
WHERE
```

Comment: Add some more sample table data, and also specify the expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a subquery, so all you need are parentheses:

```
SELECT * 
FROM T1
WHERE IMPACT > (SELECT T2.PRIORITY FROM T2 WHERE T2.URGENCY = 2)
```

This assumes that the subquery returns one row (or zero rows, in which case nothing is returned).  If the subquery can return more than one row, you should ask another question and be very explicit about what you want done.

One reasonable interpretation (for more than one row) is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM T1
WHERE IMPACT > (SELECT MAX(T2.PRIORITY) FROM T2 WHERE T2.URGENCY = 2)
```

Comment: but what if T2 has some n number of rows where n > 1 which meets the condition?

Answer (score 2):

I would use `exists`:

```
select t1.* 
from t1 
where exists (select 1 from t2 where t1.IMPACT > t2.PRIORITY);
```